# Reveal modal not functioning after Ajax call without refreshing page

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog, reveal.js

I am not entirely sure if the following is enough information but if I describe the issue some of the jQuery aficionados may recognise it. I have a button. When I click it, it activates a modal (reveal-modal-refer --- I'm using the reveal modal plugin). This opacifies the background by applying a background modal (reveal-modal-bg).

The following ajax call handles the users input of an email address into the modal, on success, it reloads the modal with a message ('result') then fades, and then the the background modal (reveal-modal-bg) opacifying the background also fades and we are left with the screen before the button is clicked. This all works fine, but if I click the button again, without a page refresh, all I get is the bacground modal, but not the input box (reveal-modal-refer)

```
    $(document.body).on("click", "#refer_it", function(){
    var email = $('#refer_input').val();
    var thread_id = $('#thread_id_for_referral').val();
    var user_id = $('#user_id_for_referral').val();
    $.ajax({
    url: '../email_scripts/refer_email_action_script.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
          'email': $('#refer_input').val(),
          'thread_id': $('#thread_id_for_referral').val(),
          'user_id' : $('#user_id_for_referral').val(),
          },
            success: function(html) {
                  var result = "Question sent";
                  $('.reveal-modal-refer').load('refer_box.php', {result: result, thread_id:thread_id}).delay(1000).fadeOut(500);
                  $('.reveal-modal-bg').delay(1500).fadeOut(500);
              }
            });
   return false;
 });
```

I am sure someone recognising this behaviour - I am new to jQuery but I suppose in lay persons terms its like the button is fixed and can't response properly to the reveal modal plugin.

Many thanks for the time taken to look.

Answer (score 0):

When the click event begins, try put

```
$('.reveal-modal-refer').show();
```

When your Ajax is finished it is fading out the 'reveal-modal-refer' element, you should make sure it is visible first.

Comment: Unfortunately this modal is loaded, then a delay, then a fade out so its definitely visible. But thanks for the input